# accessing variable in activity from database

Tags: android, variables, android-sqlite

i have an interplay between the MainActivity and the DatabaseAdapter class where I'm trying to access an integer variable from the MainActivity. The code as follows;

in MainActivity...

```
           int clam = 7;
           public void onClick_UpdateJ(View v) {
        myDb.updateJ();         
                       }
```

in DbAdapter

```
          public class { 
                 .....
                    public void updateJ(){
         int grape = "coli = ?;

        ContentValues arges = new ContentValues();
        arges.put(coli, 7);

        // Insert it into the database.
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, arges, grape, new int[]{1});
    }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to update the coli data (integer) in the database from the current 1 to 7. How do I do this? I tried shifting everything in DbAdapter to MainActivity but the 'update' method is not recognized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error? you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. There were two problems depending how I implement it. If the updateJ stays in DBAdapter, I don't know how to read the clam variable from MainActivity, and also the db.update is not recognized (solved below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void updateJ(int value) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("coli", value);
    String where = "coli = ?";
    whereArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(1) };
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, where, whereArgs);
}
```

The update method takes 4 arguments:

`table (String)`: the table name

`values (ContentValues)`: the values to insert

`selection (String)`: a SQLite `WHERE` clause. You already know that the ? character will be replaced by values in selectionArgs.

`selectionArgs (String[])`: values that replace ?s in the where clause

Comment: This code may help but it would be much more useful if there was also an explanation of how this code answers the users question.

Comment: Thanks, Karakuri. It works and your explanation helps me understand it better. Didn't have to spell it out as updateJ(int value){} tho since it works with updateJ(){} only. I would really appreciate if you could teach me how to pass the variable clam from MainActivity to be read by DBAdapter?

Comment: Just figured it out. Thanks, it took me a while to understand the (int value).. I've got a lot to learn, obviously

Comment: That's why i made `updateJ` take an argument. You can pass `clam` to it.